# How to speed up runtime of mutliple Insert Into/Select From statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, runtime

The first thing I do is create a temp table, and then insert data into that temp table. Each individual insert could be anywhere from 1,500 to 9,000 records.

The table creation, and one `insert into`/`select` from statement is as follows:

```
create table #temp_table (
    [col1] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [col3] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [col4] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [col5] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [col6] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [col7] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [col8] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [col9] [int] NOT NULL
)

--single insert into/select from statement
insert into #temp_table (
col1
, col2
, col3
, col4
, col5
, col6
, col7
, col8
, col9
) Select pt.col1
, pt.col2
, pt.col3
, pt.col4
, pt.col5
, pt.col6
, pt.col7
, pt.col8
, pt.col9
from dbo.permanent_table as pt
where pt.col6 between getdate()-14 and getdate()-7
and pt.col7 is not NULL
and pt.col6 is not NULL
```

This works exactly as intended, and in a matter of 1 second, 2 at the most. Then I add a second, and third `insert into`/`select from` statement (the `where` clause changes each time) and run time increases to about 4 seconds total. When I add the fourth `insert into`/`select from` it jumps up to 3 minutes or longer. ***How do I get runtime back down where it should be (5, maybe 6 seconds)?***

**Note:** This problem is still the case when I use the `union all` method as well.

Example of `union all` method:

```
create table #temp_table (
    [col1] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [col3] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [col4] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [col5] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [col6] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [col7] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [col8] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [col9] [int] NOT NULL
)

--union all method of inserting
insert into #temp_table (
col1
, col2
, col3
, col4
, col5
, col6
, col7
, col8
, col9
) 
--select statement 1
Select pt.col1
, pt.col2
, pt.col3
, pt.col4
, pt.col5
, pt.col6
, pt.col7
, pt.col8
, pt.col9
from dbo.permanent_table as pt with (nolock)
where pt.col7 between getdate()-14 and getdate()-7
and pt.col8 is not NULL
and pt.col7 is not NULL
union all
--select statement 2
Select pt.col1
, pt.col2
, pt.col3
, pt.col4
, pt.col5
, pt.col6
, pt.col10 as [col7]
, pt.col11 as [col8]
, pt.col9
from dbo.permanent_table as pt with (nolock)
where pt.col10 between getdate()-14 and getdate()-7
and pt.col11 is not NULL
and pt.col10 is not NULL
--select statement 3
Select pt.col1
, pt.col2
, pt.col3
, pt.col4
, pt.col5
, pt.col6
, pt.col12 as [col7]
, pt.col13 as [col8]
, pt.col9
from dbo.permanent_table as pt with (nolock)
where pt.col12 between getdate()-14 and getdate()-7
and pt.col13 is not NULL
and pt.col12 is not NULL
--select statement 4
Select pt.col1
, pt.col2
, pt.col3
, pt.col4
, pt.col5
, pt.col6
, pt.col14 as [col7]
, pt.col15 as [col8]
, pt.col9
from dbo.permanent_table as pt with (nolock)
where pt.col14 between getdate()-14 and getdate()-7
and pt.col15 is not NULL
and pt.col14 is not NULL
```

Comment: First of all how long it takes to retrieve data for 1,2,3 and for `SELECT` without `INSERT`?

Comment: It would probably be better to break this into multiple inserts. I suspect the actual performance problem is all those select statements unioned together. Also, be careful with that nolock hint, it is NOT a performance tool. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @lad2025 Insert 1 by itself, 1 sec (7679 records). Insert 2 by itself, 1 sec (7344 records). Insert 3 by itself, 1 sec (8053 records). Insert 4 by itself, 2 sec (1624 records). Insert 1 through 3 together, 4 sec. Insert 1 through 4 together, 3 min.

Comment: @SeanLange As stated in the question, this is happening both with separate `insert`/`select` statements and with the `union all` method.

Comment: Well without details about the tables involved here it is impossible to say why this is happening. Table structures, indexes, the queries being executed, execution plans all have a huge bearing on performance. Depending on the size of the transaction and the transaction log autogrowth could even have a big impact here.

Comment: Also, it will be helpful to say why you are creating the temp table, what is its final purpose in life :-) .  I still have a suggestion. Create a user defined function that evaluates all of those criteria in the various sql statements and returns status flags or even output fields where they ae conditional. That way, it will all be a single SQL statement, but the complexity hidden inside a user-defined function. You could also write that without a UDF, using a series of nested case phrases, but that would be too big and unreadable, but still functional.

Comment: Just an idea, assuming the four selects retrieve roughly the same amount of data and lacking execution plans etc:
Four separate select-inserts fit in the same space of the memory, transaction log, possibly an invisible temp table to perform the unions. On the other hand, four separate select may use the same space - no need to grow anything. This could be the reason.